# Variable argument list in Renderscript

Tags: c99, renderscript

I'm porting a few larger video codecs to Renderscript. I have just manage to port libx264 and have it encode to a raw H.264 stream. I did that by merging the library using CIL and making globals static, as well as porting Androids own libc string and some stdio functions (merging) and a heap allocation function that use a preallocated buffer.

Now I want to port libvpx. This library uses variable arguments to more central functions than libx264 did (basically the only part I needed to comment out in libx264 was the logging the rest is just configured correct and a few macro definitions to replace things).

So my question is has anyone any tip of how to use variable argument lists for static functions in Renderscript? Google state that Renderscript is C99 compliant so it must be possible in some manner. If anyone have a suggestion for a hack for this let me know if it is not currently supported.

/Harald

Answer (score 0):

In your SDK directory, you can find that the header stdarg.h is in fact included at ./android-sdks/platform-tools/renderscript/clang-include/stdarg.h. If you add

```
#include "stdarg.h"
```

with you normal include statements, the compiler seems to understand what you are talking about. I have no practical way of testing this beyond compile though.

[EDIT] I just received a "llvm-rs-cc.exe has stopped working" message in windows. The stack dump from the console says that it failed when parsing the sample function I added to see if varargs would compile. Here is the stack dump. The compiler crashes every time. My guess is that it is supported in theory but that the compiler does not handle it properly.

```
Stack dump:
0.  engine.rs:882:32: current parser token ';'
1.  engine.rs:876:1: parsing function body 'average'
2.  engine.rs:876:1: in compound statement ('{}')
```

After deleting the function but leaving the header include, the following makes it into the console (without the crash):

```
C:\android-sdks\platform-tools\renderscript\clang-include\stdarg.h:30:9: error: unknown type name '__builtin_va_list'
C:\android-sdks\platform-tools\renderscript\clang-include\stdarg.h:48:9: error: unknown type name '__builtin_va_list'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is about as far as I get also. It seems like they have forgotten to handle the __builtin_va_* functions and type *={start, end, arg, list}. I know it is not easy to do this since it is very target dependent. For example __builtin_va_start takes the variable just before the "..." as input. If this is on the stack and we know in what direction the stack grows this can be used to get the pointer to the first arg, but that is very target and compiler dependent. Usually some args are passed in registers. But I assume that the LLVM IR/bitcode have some info about this.

Comment: Yea. RenderScript is still very much in its infancy. As the documentation points out the intended goal is to have it run on many different processor types which with something so target dependent could be a very difficult thing to accomplish. Google points out that certain features have already not been included as it prevents them from guaranteeing that the code run on all targets. Perhaps as the environment grows they will add this feature but it seems that for now at least, it is not a possibility.